# How can i change "Energy Saver Status" in windows

Tags: c++

I want to change  "**Energy Saver Status**" in my application.
But I cannot find any way to do it.
Anyone could help me?

"the about setting in System->power and batetry -> batetry"

I only find the way to receive notifications when the status changes。

Comment: sorry, I had edit it.@ÖöTiib

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: in fact，I don't know how to start. I'm looking for such code@Friedrich

Comment: I found  the code  could change  some setting in "Energy Saver Status"  ,but i still no way to turn on or tuen off the  "Energy Saver Status".                                                                                                         `powercfg /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_ENERGYSAVER ESBATTTHRESHOLD 0
powercfg /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_ENERGYSAVER ESBRIGHTNESS 100`